# Read contents of <script> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to read the source of a website with the following:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url     = 'http://www.myurl.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
request = urllib2.Request(url,None,headers)
soup    = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
```

I further narrow it down as `scriptResults = soup('script',{'type' : 'text/javascript'})`. A sample of its contents is as follows:

```
scriptResults = [<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>,
                 ...,
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     //comment 1
                     $(function () {
                     //comment 2
                     var True = true, False = false;
                         func.start({
                             token1 : "...",
                             token2 : [...],
                             ...
                             tokenN : ["value1","value2",...,"valueK"],
                             ...
                         })
                     })
                 </script>,
                 ...
                 ]
```

Now I'm interested in extracting the values in `tokenN`. I know that it is unique in the entire document and is present in all the webpages I'm trying to read. Further, the number of results in `scriptResults` can vary and the number of tokens can also vary, so I can't use a position index to access it. Also, I realize `BeautifulSoup` is a HTML parser and does not parse JS. How would I go about extracting this info using regex?

If there isn't an easy way of getting them *all*, the following can be a compromise. *Most* of the `values` are of the form `"string1/xxxx/string2"`, where `xxxx` is some random SHA hash that's different for each and I can figure out the rest by other means. So if I can find only the ones that fit this pattern, it should be ok.

---

**EDIT**

In response to eyquem, I've uploaded the relevant portions before and after what I want to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AXGhHTS9). I'm interested in retrieving the values in `pageUrls`.

Comment: Also, before anyone asks for the actual website, it's accessible only internally, so won't be of much help in the question...

Comment: There are some JavaScript/ECMAScript parsers for python. Modifying one of them to extract certain information is some work and will be ugly, but not too hard.

Comment: What do you mean by that: _" the number of results in scriptResults can vary"_ ?

Comment: @eyquem I mean that if I run it on one page, I can, for example, get back 6 results (meaning there are 6 `<script>` tags in the page that are `text/javascript`) and on another page, I can get 5 or 8, I don't know. If they all were the same (e.g. 6), I could just use a position index to access it.

Comment: OK. So, from a page, you want to extract all the lines **token12 : ["value1","value2",...,"valueK"]** for example, if you're interested to the lines with N==12 ? And according to the <script> >/script> tag examined, a line with **token12** may not exist in it but may exist in the following tag ?

Comment: @eyquem They're not exactly in serial order. What I meant is that I can guarantee that `pageUrls` will be present somewhere in the entire document inside a `<script> </script>` pair, but it need not necessarily be in a particular pair. I've uploaded the relevant parts to pastebin. See my edit to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, execute the following code and post the result. I will write a regex to catch data  you want to obtain.

Nota: it would be easier if you post it in my email and it won't encumber the SO memory

```
sock = urllib2.urlopen(request)
ch = sock.read()
sock.close()

print '\n'.join(str(i) + '  ' + repr(line)
                for i,line in enumerate(ch.splitlines(True)))
```

A regex is at least 20 times faster than using BeautifulSoup to analyze a text.

I say **"analyze"** NOT **"parse"**
(for people believing that an HTML text must not be analyzed with a regex, I say: ùù&ùè-_,  sp*µùy43é' ##{[|:ù %yy~é"&'[[é(+F+"§.N/.M%%iyuo£$$ö!!!! sskrftttt §!!)

### Edit 1

If the text is organized as regularly as it seems, you even don't need a regex to analyze it:

```
from io import StringIO

ss = '''<input type="hidden" name="__FOO" id="__FOO" value="garble" />

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function () {
    // convert to 
    var True = true, False = false;

    manatee.start({
        pageIDs: ["16798", "16799", "16800", "16801", "16802"],
        userNames: ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Eve"],
        wordCounts: [77,23,64,89,93],
        linkCounts: [2,0,3,1,4],
        pageUrls: ["","/blog/35318264c9a98faf79965c270ac80c5606774df1/data.pdf","/blog/da6645f6e22bf5f75974dc7eed5fcd6160d6b51e/data.pdf","/blog/6f90f101115140727c43cadee0b9e17881403a63/data.pdf","/blog/333584fc2850d1a1f97a0a7bf8c5a12e684856bf/data.pdf","/blog/9a018ecc48a37a9247a6404fd83e085384b445aa/data.pdf"],

        toolbar: {
            id: "ManateeToolbar",
            buttons: [
                {
                    id: "ManateeBrowser",
                    text: "Enter Fullscreen",
                    toggleText: "Escape Fullscreen"
                }
            ]
        }

    });
});
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">var blah</script>'''



simili_file = StringIO(ss)

for line in simili_file:
    if line[0:13] == '\t\tpageUrls: [':
        urls = tuple(el[1:-1] for el in line[13:line.find(']')].split(',') if el[1:-1])           
    print( urls )
```

result

```
('/blog/35318264c9a98faf79965c270ac80c5606774df1/data.pdf',
'/blog/da6645f6e22bf5f75974dc7eed5fcd6160d6b51e/data.pdf', 
'/blog/6f90f101115140727c43cadee0b9e17881403a63/data.pdf', 
'/blog/333584fc2850d1a1f97a0a7bf8c5a12e684856bf/data.pdf', 
'/blog/9a018ecc48a37a9247a6404fd83e085384b445aa/data.pdf')
```

### Edit 2

In order to make the code safer relatively to variations of content in the file, you can also use a regex, though:

```
ss = '''<input type="hidden" name="__FOO" id="__FOO" value="garble" />

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function () {
    // convert to 
    var True = true, False = false;

    manatee.start({
        pageIDs: ["16798", "16799", "16800", "16801", "16802"],
        userNames: ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Eve"],
        wordCounts: [77,23,64,89,93],
        linkCounts: [2,0,3,1,4],
        pageUrls: ["","/blog/35318264c9a98faf79965c270ac80c5606774df1/data.pdf","/blog/da6645f6e22bf5f75974dc7eed5fcd6160d6b51e/data.pdf","/blog/6f90f101115140727c43cadee0b9e17881403a63/data.pdf","/blog/333584fc2850d1a1f97a0a7bf8c5a12e684856bf/data.pdf","/blog/9a018ecc48a37a9247a6404fd83e085384b445aa/data.pdf"],

        toolbar: {
            id: "ManateeToolbar",
            buttons: [
                {
                    id: "ManateeBrowser",
                    text: "Enter Fullscreen",
                    toggleText: "Escape Fullscreen"
                }
            ]
        }

    });
});
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">var blah</script>'''


import re


regx = re.compile('^\t*pageUrls[\t ]*:[\t ]*\[(.*?)\],[\t ]*$',re.MULTILINE)

for mat in regx.finditer(ss):
    urls = tuple(el[1:-1] for el in mat.group(1).split(',') if el[1:-1])
    print( urls )
```

For a good functioning of the two codes, there must not be **','** in the urls.

In the first code, there also must not be **']'** in the urls. But I verified: on Windows, repertories names can have **']'** in them.
I wrote the regex pattern of the second code in order to avoid problems due to ',' or ']' in the urls: that's with the ending part of the regex `],[\t ]*$` that requires that the ']' character must be followed only by blanks or tabs until the end of the line. Because of the star '*' after `[\t ]` the presence of tabs or blanks at the end of the line are only possible, not mandatory.

Comment: What is your variable `i` in `str(i)` above? Did you  mean `str(line)`?

Comment: Also, there's a lot of personal identifying info there, so I'll strip out irrelevant parts/replace with lorem ipsum

Comment: Oh, you'll remove the telephone number of Pamela Anderson ?, What a pity !

Comment: In fact, I don't need all the page (that's precisely why a regex can be used: I won't parse the page). What is needed is only a section of the text beginning at the end of a tag and ending at the beginning of another tag, with a complete tag in the middle. We will iterate the research.

Comment: _"Did you mean str(line)"_ No, I mean **repr(line)**. This function displays the escaped characters : so we can see the characters \n \r \t , they are not to be guessed. It makes easy to write a regex.

Comment: I had to make some changes to the first one. I changed `io.StringIO` to `StringIO.StringIO` to avoid an error. Perhaps you're using v3.0? I'm using 2.7. Secondly, the tabs are counted as 4 spaces and instead of `line[0:13]`, I had to change it to `line[0:19]`. This I presume is due to different OS (I'm on a mac). The regex solution doesn't work and I presume it's for the same reason (i.e. `\t` is not properly capturing the tabs/spaces). How would you modify it? Is it `\s` for any white space? Nevertheless, I've upvoted your answer since I can follow what you're doing and the regex makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I used 3.2 for this code. In fact, I usually use 2.7 but to verifiy something I read in another answer on SO, I temporarily installed 3.2.

Comment: A tab can't be counted as 4 spaces because a tab is represented by '\t' in a text. If there's a count of 4 chars somewhere, that's because there are 4 chars. I copied the RAW text on pastebin , in which there are two tabs before 'pageUrls:' as it can be seen when we pass the mouse over this place and select it; while there are 16 blank spaces in the numbered text above. I don't know what made 8 characters transformed into two tabs during transfer to pastebin

Comment: It is to avoid such problems that I asked you to post the text treated with **repr()**. The splitlines(True) is to keep the original newlines and the printing of the enumeration of lines, joined with '\n', is to obtain a display easy to read. What counts toi write a regex pattern  is what is seen after the dispay by my little snippet

Comment: People commonly use '\s' to symbolize blank space in regex patterns, but I don't because this symbol exceeds the need: it represents the set of characters ``[ \f\n\r\t\v]`` but there are rarely ``\f`` and ``\v`` in a text. Moreover, when the need is to represent a blank space or a tab, it isn't necessary to use a symbol that will also represent ``\r`` and ``\n``, it could produce erors, why not.... The less a regex has to represent, the best it is for the speed , simplicity and precision. - Simply replace ``^\t*pageUrls`` with ``^[ \t]*pageUrls`` at the beginning of the pattern

Comment: Perfect! Replacing it with `^[ \t]` helped. My apologies about the `repr()`. I accidentally copied the output from a different terminal where I had the original source code displayed. Never realized that I was copying the incorrect one. Anyway, this works and I think I have enough of a lead here to figure the rest of my script/modify the regex on my own :) Thanks.

Comment: _"I think I have enough of a lead here to figure the rest of my script/modify the regex on my own"_ I think so too. Modify and maintain. Because it is never sure that a regex will be OK forever for a text, it may happen some changing or special case that spoils the result from time to time, and then it is necessary to adapt the pattern. Hope it will be useful a long time. Thanks you for upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach to give you an alternative data point. Here is an extractor for your problem using pyparsing instead of regex. You might find this easier to maintain in the long run:

```
from pyparsing import Literal, quotedString, removeQuotes, delimitedList

# automatically strip quotes from quoted strings
# quotedString matches single or double quotes
quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)

# define a pattern to extract the pageUrls: entry
pageUrlsSpec = Literal('pageUrls:') + '[' + delimitedList(quotedString)('urls') + ']'

for pageUrls in pageUrlsSpec.searchString(ss):
    for url in pageUrls.urls:
        print url
```

Prints:

```
/blog/35318264c9a98faf79965c270ac80c5606774df1/data.pdf
/blog/da6645f6e22bf5f75974dc7eed5fcd6160d6b51e/data.pdf
/blog/6f90f101115140727c43cadee0b9e17881403a63/data.pdf
/blog/333584fc2850d1a1f97a0a7bf8c5a12e684856bf/data.pdf
/blog/9a018ecc48a37a9247a6404fd83e085384b445aa/data.pdf
```

Comment: This actually looks a lot neater. I will try both approaches and will consider accepting this if I indeed find it easier (it certainly looks like it!). Thanks :)